# How to dynamically inject a background script in manifest v3 extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

we have some scripts that needs to be injected only when a setting is enabled by the user and not on the initial load itself, earlier in mv2 we have injected using a  tag in background by script.src ="myscript" , then document.body.append(script). But since we cannot access the window object from background, what are the other possible ways to inject?

pls suggest any possible solution

Comment: Use importScripts dynamically as shown in [this answer](/a/66408379) or do it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).